# Updation of a shared object that is created inside factory method of a module is not updating in another module in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-controller, ng-app, ng-modules

Hello I am a beginner in Angular JS and now I am stuck into something. 
I have made two modules

**Menu** and **Canvas**

Now I have declared a object inside the factory method of **Menu** module to make it available from **Canvas** module.

My code is as follow;

```
var Menu=angular.module("menu",[]);

Menu.factory("Data",['$rootScope', function($rootScope){

    var obj={};
    obj.server="http://localhost:8080";
    obj.transformations=null;
    obj.actions=null;
    obj.sources=null;
    obj.typeSelected=null;

    obj.save = function(data) {
         $rootScope.$broadcast('data:updated',data);
       }

    return obj;
}]);
```

Now I have a controller that update the values of *obj*'s attributes.

```
Menu.controller("menuClick",function($scope,Data){

    $scope.obj=Data;

    $scope.clickOnMenu=function(type)
    {
        if(type.indexOf("Source")!=-1)$scope.obj.typeSelected="source";
        else if(type.indexOf("Transformation")!=-1)$scope.obj.typeSelected="transformation";
        else if(type.indexOf("Action")!=-1)$scope.obj.typeSelected="action";

        console.log($scope.obj);

        //added bootstrap here
        angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById("canvascontainer"), ['canvas']);
    }
})
```

Now when I am creating the **Canvas** module I am adding dependency of **Menu** module

```
var Canvas=angular.module('canvas',['menu']);

Canvas.controller("canvasOperation",["Data",'$scope',function(Data,$scope){

    $scope.obj=Data;

    $scope.clickCanvas=function()
    {
        console.log($scope.obj)
        if($scope.obj.typeSelected!=null)
        {
         console.log("fun started");
        }
    }
}])
 //removed it from here
//angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById("canvascontainer"), ['canvas']);
```

Now the problem is even after I update the *typeSelected* value from *clickOnMenu* method of **Menu** module the value of *typeSelected* is not updating in **Canvas** module and in **Canvas** module;

```
console.log($scope.obj.typeSelected)
```

giving output **null**.

I tried to explain every details. Can you please tell me where am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think when you bootstrap the `canvas` module. Injected `menu` module also load, but the values assign inside `menuClick` will not execute. Did you check if `menu Click` is getting executed when bootstrap the module

Comment: No menuClick is being executed only when I click on something.

Comment: so that mean without executing menuClick the values not set in the factory. thats why `$scope.obj.typeSelected` is null initially.

Comment: So can you please suggest me how to achieve when the value of obj.typeSelected is changed, I can get it from Canvas module?

Comment: bootstrap the canvas before click on the menuClick

Comment: Ok, let me try.

Comment: No luck yet. Take a look at my edited code. It is still showing null.

Comment: angular.bootstrap creates a new $rootScope and a new $injector on the specified element that is different than the $rootscope created by the `ng-app` directive.  The `Data` service constructed for the `ng-app` injector is different than the `Data` service constructed on the `canvascontainer` element and its injector. angular.bootstrap shouldn't be called from inside Angular. What are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: Ok, actually I want when a menu is clicked after that if I click on a div "canvas" something 'll happen once and after that I have to click on menu again.